# nul value in text file when opening notepad++ causing reading issue

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file generated from one of friends process. The issue is when we open the textfile after its generated in notepad++ it has the text we want but in some of the lines there is a value that says 'nul'.

Can anyone tell me what does 'nul' mean and why its showing up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In many computer languages, strings are "Null-terminated" - the last character of a string is set to a value of 0, so that the program processing it knows it's the end.

If you write a value of 0 as a character (not the actual character '0', which is 0x30, but a value of 0x00) than that's interpreted as a null character (or NUL). Many functions will strip the null-terminator before writing the string to a file, but as you haven't specified your method, I can't comment one way or another.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character for more info.